# Как сделать замену

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Здравствуйте. У меня есть участок кода такого вида:

```
<div id="s"><p>Text</p></div>
```

Как заменить содержимое `DIV`'а на что-то вроде

```
<div id="s"><input type="text" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на jquery:

```
$("div#s").html('<input type="text" />');
```